# How to get the value of an attribute from a SQL query with PHP

Tags: php, sql

I'm doing a website with HTML and PHP. PHP connects a database in MySQL php MyAdmin with the website that I'm doing. I can show the results from the SQL query with the next code:

```
<table width="90%" border="1" align="center" bgcolor="white" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">

        <tr>
        <td><strong>Nombre Destino</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Cantidad Hoteles</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Cantidad Estrellas</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Estrellas</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <br><br>
    <?php

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
    {       
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row["NOMBRED"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row["CANT_HOTELES"]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row["CANTESTRELLAS"]."</td>";
    if (echo $row["CANTESTRELLAS"] ==1) {
        "<td>"."<img src='http://pngimg.com/upload/star_PNG1597.png' style='width:10%'>"."</td>";
    }
    echo"</tr>";
    }
}
```

The problem that I have is the following: If a hotel has 5 starts, in the column "Estrellas", I have to show 5 images of a little star. I was thinking about making an If statement, but it doesn't work. Can you please help me?

Comment: Is it going to be customers grade that makes the number of stars? If yes, then how are you going to do if I give five stars and you four? You need to create a "negative" mask of the stars and use a solid color image behind the mask that you set the width of as a % (the average).

Comment: Also `if (echo $row["CANTESTRELLAS"] ==1) {` probably needs to be change to `if ($row["CANTESTRELLAS"] ==1) {`

Comment: I changed it using     if ($row["CANTESTRELLAS"] ==1), but it doesn't work either. Also, the number of stars are given in the database, so they don't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to display as many `<img` as `$row["CANTESTRELLAS"]` indicates :

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
{       
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row["NOMBRED"]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row["CANT_HOTELES"]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row["CANTESTRELLAS"]."</td>";
echo "<td>";
for ( $i = 0; $i < $row["CANTESTRELLAS"]; $i++ ) // <=== DISPLAY ESTRELLAS.
   echo "<img src='http://pngimg.com/upload/star_PNG1597.png'style='width:10%'>";
echo "</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: I was trying the code and I notice the error. Thank you! This was really helpful!!!